# Making Swift Class With Character Or Character-Based Property Codable

Tags: swift, character, protocols, codable

It appears that the Character class in Swift 4 does not implement the Codable protocol. I would like to understand the rationale for this, as it seems that the class would qualify as a foundational class in Swift.

Looking at the (intentionally stripped bare) recursive class below, what would then be the best way to make it Codable while retaining the use of Character as the Dictionary key?

```
class MyClass: Codable { <- does not compile
    var myProperty: [Character: MyClass]?
    var myOtherProperty: Int = 42
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: You just need to make `Character` conform to `Codable` in an extension. As for the rationale, no one knows for sure except for the Swift developers, but since you can easily convert a `Character` to `String` and vice-versa, it's quite unprobable that a lot of people would want to encode/decode plain `Character` instances to/from JSON rather than using `String`s.

Comment: Thanks! I suspected that was the answer, and as for why Character is not Codable, as you say, only they know indeed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make `Character` conform to `Codable` protocol as follow:

```
extension Character: Codable {
    public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        var container = try decoder.unkeyedContainer()
        let string = try container.decode(String.self)
        guard !string.isEmpty else {
            throw DecodingError.dataCorruptedError(in: container, debugDescription: "Decoder expected a Character but found an empty string.")
        }
        guard string.count == 1 else {
            throw DecodingError.dataCorruptedError(in: container, debugDescription: "Decoder expected a Character but found a string: \(string)")
        }
        self = string[string.startIndex]
    }
    public func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.unkeyedContainer()
        try container.encode(String(self))
    }
}
```

---

Playground testing

```
let aClass = AClass()
let bClass = AClass()
bClass.myOtherProperty = 10
aClass.myProperty = [:]
aClass.myProperty?["B"] = bClass
aClass.myOtherProperty = 20
do {
    let jsonData = try JSONEncoder().encode(aClass)
    print(String(data: jsonData, encoding: .utf8)!)  // "{"myProperty":[["B"],{"myOtherProperty":10}],"myOtherProperty":20}\n"
    let decodedObject = try JSONDecoder().decode(AClass.self, from: jsonData)
    print(decodedObject.myProperty)      // "Optional(["B": __lldb_expr_73.AClass])\n"
    print(decodedObject.myOtherProperty) // 20
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```